# How do I get a Wordpress custom function using $_GET to return a value using an id from a urlencode?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm transferring a site into wordpress and I'm trying to send an id from the urlencode of a list/menu in the main template to a $_GET superglobal in the header template. Although the urlencode is working, the function using the $_GET superglobal doesn't seem to be returning a value.

This is the part where the function is called to handle the id value from the urlencode.

```
if (isset($_GET['opt'])) {
$sel_state = get_state_by_id($_GET['opt']);
} else {
$sel_state = NULL;
}
```

This is the function in functions.php that is supposed to return a variable to assign to $sel_state so I can show values from the row in the main template page.

```
function get_state_by_id($state_id) 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sel_state_row = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->state_menu_list WHERE id = " . $state_id 
. " LIMIT 1" );
    return $sel_state_row;  
}
```

This is the beginning of the section where the $sel_state variable is assigned to variables that will be displayed on the main template page.

```
global $sel_state;          
$main_gov_page_url = $sel_state->main_gov_page_url;
// ...the other values in the row.
```

Is there a way to make this work without a plugin 
using something like query_vars? If I need a plugin 
to do this could someone point me in the right 
direction?

Comment: There is an SQL Injection in your code. The $state_id in the query needs to be escaped $wpdb->_real_escape($state_id)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to quite change the code, you have to add filter in function.php file, and then you can call the function which you have added in function.php

In function.php,

```
function get_state_by_id_function($state_id) 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sel_state_row = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->state_menu_list WHERE id = " . $state_id 
. " LIMIT 1" );
    return $sel_state_row;  
}
add_filter( 'get_state_by_id', 'get_state_by_id_function');
```

Now you have to call `get_state_by_id` where ever you want, in your case:

```
if (isset($_GET['opt'])) {
$sel_state = get_state_by_id($_GET['opt']);
} else {
$sel_state = NULL;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Same as the ops code you have an SQL Injection in your code also. The $state_id in the query needs to be escaped $wpdb->_real_escape($state_id)

Comment: Thanks for the information I ended up getting it to work with a plugin. I'll make sure to close it off to sql injection before it goes online. Thanks.